# jquery tabs, jpages "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ?"

Tags: jquery

I'm using two popular technologies, jquery tabs and jPages.  Unfortunately the target below does not seem to be cooperating.  Can this be fixed in the current setup for the three pages I've put below?

```
$("div.holder").jPages({containerID : "card-row"});
```

Page 1 (using jquery tabs):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul><li><a href="pages/page-2.php">Your Collection</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Page 2 (uses ajax):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/pages/page-3.php",{}, function(data, statusTxt){
        $('#collection-table .search-results').html(data);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="#collection-table">
    <div class="search-results">
    <!-- get page 3 contents-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Page 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jpage.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("div.holder").jPages({
      containerID : "card-row",
      previous : "?",
      next : "?",
      perPage : 20,
      delay : 20
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="holder">
<!-- pagination pages-->
</div>
<tbody id="card-row">
<!--rows-->
</tbody>
```

Comment: `previous` and `next` are expecting jQuery selector strings. `?` isn't a valid selector.

Comment: I see what happened here.  I copy and pasted from the demo and the text editor didn't like the characters.  Thanks.